# Is there any ways to accept implicit conversion from one element initializer list but not a single value?

Tags: c++, initialization

The question itself may be confusing, so I'll describe it in detail here. Suppose we have a type `S` that represents a 1-dimensional vector (the linear algebra one, not the `std` one). Since it's kind of an array, so it's good if it behaves like `std::array<int, 1>`. Obviously, we don't want to allow construction with just a scalar, but implicit list initialization from a single element should be allowed. Shown in the following code snippet are the few initialization/conversion scenarios, I would prefer #2 and #4 to work while rejecting #1 and #3.

```cpp
struct S
{
    explicit(?) S(int value);
};

S f1() { return 0; }      // #1
S f2() { return { 0 }; }  // #2

void g()
{
    S s1 = 0;             // #3
    S s2{ 0 };            // #4
}
```

Making the constructor `explicit` would disallow #1 and #3, which is nice, but as a side effect, it also disallows #2. #2 should be allowed in this scenario, just like how `std::array<int, 1>` works.

Since the type would have other constructors defined, and I would like the data to be private, so AFAIK it's not possible to use the same technique as `std::array` (aggregate init + brace elision). Are there any means to achieve this goal? I don't mind if some bizarre tricks must be used.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

- I have tried `explicit(false) S(std::array<int, 1>);` and it works, but it needs an additional pair of braces for cases #2 and #4. It would be great if the same goal can be achieved without the extra braces.

Comment: Looking maybe for `explicit S(std::initializer_list<int> value);` ? That sort of works (needs some tweaking for your case #2, but it rules out #1 and #3, allowing #4). However, it also allows initializer lists with more than 1 element - maybe not so good?

Comment: @AdrianMole But this also accepts `S{1, 2}`, which converts a compile-time error into a runtime one, which is even worse than having to use a cumbersome syntax imo.

Comment: Yes, I see that problem. How about `explicit S(std::array<int, 1> value);` - that needs some tweaking on your #2 and #4 (adding an extra set of `{}`).

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, I have tried this approach and it works with the extra pair of braces. It would be great if there are any means to do that without the double braces though.

Comment: Also, the `explicit` *may* be a red herring. That prevents the *implicit* conversion in your `f2`, which would need to return an *explicitly* constructed object.

Comment: #2 and #4 are not lists of any kind. They are examples of "uniform initialization syntax", introduced in modern C++ as an alternative to traditional initialization, and is functionally equivalent to the traditional construction/initialization, and they cannot be distinguished or discriminated between each other.

Comment: Personally, I would look at using something like `template <typename T> my_vector_type = std::array<T,1>;`, and the you can use `make_my_vector_type` factory functions that are overloaded with the different ways you want to populate the array.  This gives you the array behavior when directly initializing the vector but still provides functionality to get more complicated construction.

Comment: @NathanOliver You definitely don't want to overload operators for `std::array` right?

Comment: While technically you shouldn't to avoid potential future overloads from the standard causing an ODR issue, if they are math operators, I can't see the standard adding any of those.

Comment: It’s silly that `explicit` doesn’t mean exactly what you want: the braced-init-list in a return statement can’t initialize any *other* type, so the argument that “you should have to name the type here” doesn’t really work.  Unfortunately the committee disagrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible.  Since `S` is not an aggregate and the initializer-list is not empty, you go straight to considering **constructors** for `return {0};`.  That's the same overload resolution as for the (non-list) copy-initialization for `return 0;`, except that explicit constructors are disallowed rather than disregarded.

Oddly enough, this means you can have the **inverse** behavior: by providing an implicit and an explicit constructor that are ambiguous for construction from `int`, you can make `return {0};` fail due to ambiguity while having `return 0;` select the converting constructor.

One might try a trick involving an **intermediate** type:

```
struct hold {hold(int);};
struct S {
  S(hold);
};
```

Unfortunately, the rules for multiple user-defined conversions are also consistent between copy- and copy-list-initialization, so the `S(hold(0))` interpretation won't be tried for either mode of construction.  (There are cases where multiple levels of braces allow multiple user-defined conversions, but that's not relevant here by hypothesis.)